# Multiplication table in Java using a method

Tags: java, for-loop

Write a method that returns a multiplication table based on two input values that specify what two ranges of numbers to multiply together. For example, if the method were given 3 and 4 as input, it would return a string that when printed, would look like this:

1   2   3   4

2   4   6   8

3   6   9   12

Output Requirements:

Each number must be followed by a tab character.
Each line must be followed by a new line character (including the last row).
The columns and rows should range from 1 to the input number.
The method signature should look as follows:

public static String multiplicationTable(int rows, int columns){}

Call the testMT() method from main after completing this method to ensure it is working as expected.

```
public static String multiplicationTable(int rows, int columns) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
                int num = i * j;
                String a = "" + num +"\t";
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return String.format("%s", a); 
    }
public static void testMT() {
     System.out.println("Testing Multiplication Table");

     String expected = "1\t2\t3\t4\t\n2\t4\t6\t8\t\n3\t6\t9\t12\t\n";
     System.out.print("Expecting:\n" + expected);

     String actual = multiplicationTable(3, 4);
     System.out.print("Actual:\n" + actual);

     boolean correct = expected.equals(actual);
     System.out.println("Outputs equal? " + correct);
     }
```

Here is my output:

Testing Multiplication Table
Expecting:

1   2   3   4
2   4   6   8
3   6   9   12

Actual:

12  Outputs equal? false

I feel like I have the right setup but I can't figure out how to get the expected output.

Comment: You're not saving the String in between iterations of you nested row, column loop.  Maybe *String a = "";* before the nested loops and *a += "" + num +"\t";* inside the nested loops.

Comment: .... and `a += "\n";` when printing new line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `multiplicationTable` method is printing, and not quite legal. Build the table and return it. Something like,

```
public static String multiplicationTable(int rows, int columns) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
            int num = i * j;
            sb.append(num).append('\t');
        }
        sb.append('\n');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

With no other changes, I then get

```
Testing Multiplication Table
Expecting:
1   2   3   4   
2   4   6   8   
3   6   9   12  
Actual:
1   2   3   4   
2   4   6   8   
3   6   9   12  
Outputs equal? true
```